# virtual wordpress install / sandbox for users or pastebin

Tags: feature-request, suggestion

Each time i try to help someone, i wish they can show me their code. most ppl are in production env. and they can not trust a total stranger and vice versa ( i wouldn't trust one)

so i was wondering if wordpress.stackexchange can create sandboxes or like virtual wordpress installs that ppl can use to test stuff and collaborate or at least some kind of paste bin where we can view the actual code instead of going and downloading plugin and trying to troubleshoot it.

I am not sure i made myself clear, hope you guys know what i am talking about and can identify the need i am trying to address .

Comment: Glad to have you here on WordPress Answers helping out!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - well, it is being part of community, i seek help also here-so the better the community the more ppl stick around :) the more help i can get ;p

Comment: Absolutely!  We all get help from each other, the more the better! 

BTW, what part of Lebanon are you from? I hosted two college kids as summer interns in Atlanta GA USA from American College in Beirut back in 2003 so I have a fondness for Lebanon.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel ah well - Lebanon is a tiny country- i lived in beirut most of college years - but currently i am in the lovely city of Jbeil/Byblos - nice to know someone has a fondness of leb (:

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@mireille raad:**

I know exactly your frustration. I am constantly leaving comments saying *"Can you **please** give me detail so that is a better chance I can **actually help you**!!!"*

But, and I can't speak for StackExchange, I would highly doubt they can or would even want to set up such a system. There's more likelihood that maybe someone who offers WordPress-based hosting could do something like this, however. Still, it would require people asking questions to actually use it, and most seem to not want to go to the trouble.

FYI, I'm writing a blog post entitled *"How to Ask a Question on StackExchange's WordPress Answers"* that I intend to simply link to the comments when someone asks a question with not enough information.  Hope to have it finished soon to that others may link to it too.

-Mike

Comment: you think at least integration of some sort of paste bin with stackexchange would help ?

Comment: @mireille raad - Maybe, but you can already paste code to a pastebin and link it so I don't think they would add it. But I decided to go the original StackExchange site where many things of platform nature are decided and it seems you may have your answers in these questions: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70043/a-stack-exchange-brand-pastebin
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70587/stack-overflow-pastebin-or-rather-a-link-to-it
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17972/submit-large-chunk-of-code-to-pastebin